# Vuetify autocomplete styling issue in scrollable container

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an application with a sidebar and a container. The sidebar is the height of the screen, but the content of the container is longer, so I added `overflow-x: hidden` to the container css, to add scrolling functionality.

Now, I'm trying to add a Vuetify autocomplete component in the container. But because of this `overflow-x` styling, the dropdown of the autocomplete component scrolls with the page, instead of sticking to the input field.

I created a codepen with some simplified code from the Vuetify documentation page, so you can check out the behavior: https://codepen.io/brm49024/pen/PoqaBzM.

So, my goal is for the dropdown to stick to the input field when scrolling. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to adjust the positioned height of the menu whenever the page scrolls.

First add the following method:

```
 fixPosition () {
      const menu = document.getElementById("app").nextElementSibling
      if (!menu) return
      const input = this.$refs['scroll-track-input'].$el.getBoundingClientRect()
      menu.style.top = input.bottom - 50 + 'px'
    }
```

And then in your template point a scroll handler to the `fixPosition` method and add a `scroll-track-input` ref to the autocomplete element.

```
<main id="container" v-scroll:#container="fixPosition">
      <v-autocomplete 
        ref="scroll-track-input"
      />
</main>
```

working example https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/JjdBWPw

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I just want to note that in my code I had the container and the autocomplete in different components. It's possible to put the `v-scroll` directive on the `v-autocomplete` and still target that id.